# Syncronization of two threads every k steps

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with Java threads. I must run two threads separately for a defined number of steps and then I have to make them communicate. 
Thread 1 must read an ArrayList that thread 2 owns and modifies and same for thread 2. 
Which is the better method to synchronize them? Can I use the arrayList of thread1 for thread 2 or must I define a different shared area?

Thank everybody.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much cleaner to use a dedicated synchronizer than to lock on one of the `ArrayList`s.
I would suggest using a [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). To quote the JavaDoc:

> *A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the situation is symmetric, you should not chose one ArrayList over the other. Use additional object. [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) looks like the best choice.